# Module Federation: Updating NextJS Remote Causes NextJS Host to throw 'Hydration failed' Error

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

Trying to figure out if I'm doing something wrong or if there's a bug...

1. I have a remote app running NextJS on port [here](https://github.com/jgf5013/nextjs-module-federation-app/tree/main). I can run that locally on port 5000 by running `npm run dev`. I can go to http://localhost:5000/user/12 and see the user details are rendered. All good.
2. Next (ha?!) I have a host app also running NextJS [here](https://github.com/jgf5013/nextjs-module-federation-host). I run that locally on port 4000 by also running `npm run dev`. Now I can go to http://localhost:4000/host-page-user/12 and see the user is rendered (without all that `api/*` logic in the host...) Perfect!
3. Now I can make a text change on the remote app by doing something small like this
   [image] The update renders on the remote app running on port 5000 without any problem. Lovely.
4. But now when I go back to my host app I get an error message that says `Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Test" Client: "Testing"` with a console log of `Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`
   [image]
   In my production environment with slightly different dependency version numbers I get `Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML`. Console error is still the same.
   [image]

Really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: We can follow the discussion here: https://github.com/module-federation/universe/issues/991

Comment: I'd be interested in a solution as well. The problem I see is that the underlying HTML that is being hydrated will always be different until a build is run. The server is still server built HTML that comes from the older version of the federated component. Unless that HTML can be dynamically generated from the server, I don't see how this can be solved.